# Undefined value: angularjs $scope and web3.eth.getBalance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ethereum

I am simply trying to return the Balance value of an ethereum account using the web3 api, I would like to get that value in the $scope so I could use it in my html. Unfortunately I always get a value is undefined. I suspect it is coming from the fact that web3 might be asynchronous but I am not sure. Here is my code:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showBalance = function(){
        web3.eth.getBalance("0xCc26fda641929192B2Fe96BBc37DB5B451Cb9A8c", 
            function(err, res){
                $scope.balance = res.c[0]
                console.log("This is inside:" + $scope.balance);
            });

        console.log("This is outside:" + $scope.balance);
    };

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.showBalance();
    });
});
```

Basically the console.log("This is inside") works and I do get the right value.
But the console.log("This is outside") doesn't and I get an undefined value.

Comment: I don't know what web3.eth.getBalance is but I assume its a promise.  If so, the code in the callback function won't get executed until the promise is resolved.  Meanwhile, the other code continues to execute.  You can see this if you step through the code while its executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunatly i always get a value is undefined. I suspect it is
>   comming from the fact that web3 might be asynchronous but I am not
>   sure.

You have guessed.

Here :

```
    web3.eth.getBalance("0xCc26fda641929192B2Fe96BBc37DB5B451Cb9A8c", 
        function(err, res){
            $scope.balance = res.c[0]
            console.log("This is inside:" + $scope.balance);
        });

    console.log("This is outside:" + $scope.balance);
```

the function(err,res) is the callback function executed when the `getBalance()` function has finished its task.
A callback function declaration is not blocking. It is only executed when the called function has finished its task and so return a promise that allows to invoke the callback function to notify its caller of the result of the task.
So when `getBlance()` function is invoked, the next executed code is :

```
console.log("This is outside:" + $scope.balance);.
```

But at this time, the callback function has not been still invoked.
That is only when the callback function is invoked that 
 `$scope.balance = res.c[0]` is executed.

Conclusion :

you should remove       `console.log("This is outside:" + $scope.balance);`.